# Webpart: Modifying Content and Compiling WSP

Tags: solution-package

So I flew the task of changing the web part.
A task. Fix a few lines so that the web part works as we need.
What do we have.

1. The web part that is installed on Sharepoint 2016.
2. Web part installer in .webpart format
3. VisualStudio

What is done. I read the literature. From various sources I learned that you need

1. decompile this file to get the contents (in my case) of 6 files. Among which was a .DLL file. And as they told me somewhere, it is necessary to work with .DLL exactly.
2. Found a decompiler [this](https://ru.wikihow.com/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-DLL%E2%80%93%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B). Which did its job and gave me a list of 6 files. (.cs .pdb .sln .csproj)
3. Opened in Visual Studio 2017 a folder with files that I received from the previous step. Found the desired problem. Changed what I needed.

And now how to collect everything? I can not do it. Visual Studio swears during assembly.
Error CS0246 Could not find the type or namespace name "....." (perhaps there is no using directive or assembly reference)
can anyone come across this. how to get out of the situation?
my knowledge of this topic is minimal. in my humble opinion, I stuck half way.
Sorry if I duplicate the question)

Comment: Decompiling .NET assemblies does not provide you with the _original_ source code. Instead, it provides you a reference guide to the code, which you can then re-implement in your own project.

Comment: @Trevor Seward  Thanks for the feedback. Do I understand correctly. The DLL file that I need to edit after any of my manipulations will not work at all ??

Comment: I'm not saying it won't work, but it will almost certainly require cleanup/fixes in order to compile.

Comment: in fact, I unpacked the dll file. Found and changed the right one. And stuck at the stage of compiling VisualBasic2017 code back to .dll
about 7 errors that I can’t know how to fix